# ImageResizer in Umbraco 7 - Cropping with resizing

Tags: umbraco7, imageresizer

I'm having an issue cropping an image and then resizing an image using ImageResizer 3.4.3 within an Umbraco site.

What I'm trying to achieve is a square crop that is anchored to the right of the image, and then resized to a specific size.

For example, with this original image:
[image]

I'm trying to get an output looking like the highlighted section of this image:
[image]

From my understanding of the ImageResizer documentation, I should be able to do this in two ways - either using:

- ?crop=(500,0,0,0)&width=150 or
- ?width=150&height=150&mode=crop&anchor=topright

The results don't seem to match what I want though - the first outputs this, applying the resize before the crop:

[image]

And the second method outputs this - ignoring the anchor parameter (centering the crop):

[image]

The only way I can get it to work is to use percentage cropping - unfortunately this won't be feasible with many of the images i'm working with (variable width):

?crop=(50,0,0,0)&cropxunits=100&cropyunits=100&height=150

[image]

Am I missing something? Should it be possible to do this?

Here is the [debug output from ImageResizer](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7698dca5b62c394e11d1).

Comment: Those exact commands work for me. Perhaps something else is mangling the querystring before it gets to ImageResizer?

Comment: You're right, it must be something to do with Umbraco 7 or the other httpModules

Answer (score 2):

After Nathanael Jones' comment I realised it must be a problem with Umbraco (7.2.2).  I tried moving the ImageResizingModule to a higher position in the order of http modules in the web.config, and everything started working as advertised.  It looks like Umbraco's ImageProcessorModule was messing with the input parameters.

All i had to do was move the ImageResizingModule above the ImageProcessorModule

```
<add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule"/>
<add name="ImageProcessorModule" type="ImageProcessor.Web.HttpModules.ImageProcessingModule, ImageProcessor.Web" />
```